# "Резиновая" верстка HTML-страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Где ставить проценты?

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
      <head>
<title>School.ua</title>
<style type="text/css/">
body.style_body
{
background-image: url(images/fon.jpg);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
direction: ltr;
display: block;
overflow-y: scroll;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.gods_area
{ 
background: #D954FF;
width:1263px;
height:82px;  
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
 }
 .info_area
 {
 background: trensparent;
 width: 500px;
 height: 516px;    
 }
 .choise_area
 {
 position: relative;
 background: trensparent;
 width: 761px;
 height: 516px;   
 margin-left: 500px;
 margin-top: -516px;
 border-left:2px solid black;
 }
.screenwriter_area
{
background: #DAABF2;;
width:1263px;
height:82px;  
border-top:2px solid black;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;   
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="style_body">
<div id="gods_area" class="gods_area"></div>
<div id="line_area" class="line_area">
<div id="info_area" class="info_area"></div>
<div id="choise_area" class="choise_area"></div>
</div>
<div id="screenwriter_area" class="screenwriter_area"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен резиновый дизайн или фиксированный? Или смешанный?

Для резинового, как вариант:

```
.info_area
{
 width: 35%;
 height: 516px;    
}
.choise_area
{
 width: 64%;
 height: 516px;   
 margin-left: 35%;
 margin-top: -516px;
 border-left:2px solid black;
}
```

Кстати, не `background: trensparent;`,  а  `background: transparent;`

И вообще, нарисуйте схему того, что Вы хотите получить, это значительно ускорит решение проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Не указывайте все в процентах! Только то, что обязательно нужно "резиновить"! Потом проблем не оберетесь, т. к. не все браузеры это абсолютно правильно воспринимают. Лучше сделайте контентблок с фиксированными размерами, а margin по бокам от него сделайте auto. Вариант уже несколько старомодный, но надежный и проверенный.

Answer (score 0):

Может потому, что "резиновый" предполагает все значения в `%`, а не `px`, как у вас?

Comment: Мне надо сделать, чтобы на разных маниторах он отображался нормально, для этого нужно все значения указать в процентах?

Comment: Проценты надо делать только в width  height.
А как указать margin-top в px

Comment: знакомы с calc для css ?